# How to animate the fill of an arc in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Is there a way we can fill color of css semi-circle in an incremental way in anticlockwise direction like a progress bar.

Here is the semi-circle code. https://jsfiddle.net/sonymax46/wqfovdjh/7/.

```
        .cc{
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80px;
}
.curve {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

I want existing blue colour to be filled with Green on an event. How to achieve this with css O SVG

Thank in Advance

Comment: Can you use an SVG instead? I can think of a few ways with CSS but an SVG might be easier.

Answer (score 2):

**Option A** is to use a container that cut's off a circular element and a pseudo-class as a "mask" over the top of the circle. Then a gradient background shows the other color when the element is rotated.

The major drawback to this is you have to have a solid color background that the overlay can match visually.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* just to show the box could be transparent */
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  /* Use relative on parent so mask aligns */
  left: 50%;
  /* Move the circle 'outside' the wrapper */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(55, 238, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(55, 238, 79, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.arc:after {
  /* this creates the 'mask' */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper:hover .arc {
  /* rotate the full element because we can't transition backgrounds */
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.gradientExample {
  /* just to show the gradient */
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(55, 238, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(55, 238, 79, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
}

p {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the arc</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arc"></div>
</div>
<div class="gradientExample"></div>
```

**Option B** - Use a `clip-path` instead of overlapping elements. This is much better but you need to create an SVG object to use for the arc and that's a pain from a sizing standpoint.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.svgArc {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}

.svgArc:after {
  /* have to use a pseudo element because we can't rotate the background */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(55, 238, 79, 1) 0%, rgba(55, 238, 79, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.v2:hover .svgArc:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

p {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the gray square</p>

<div class="wrapper v2">
  <div class="svgArc">

  </div>
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="svgPath">
     <path fill="#000000" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" d="M100,0 L100,10 L100,10 C50.2943725,10 10,50.2943725 10,100 C10,149.705627 50.2943725,190 100,190 L100,200 L100,200 C44.771525,200 0,155.228475 0,100 C0,44.771525 44.771525,0 100,0 Z"></path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**Option C** - Create an SVG circle and animate the `offset-path`. See my answer and example here: [How to make linear css transition to SVG path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400356/how-to-make-linear-css-transition-to-svg-path)

Answer (score 0):

maybe with css custom variables ?

```js
const Root   = document.documentElement
  ,  btColor = document.getElementById('bt-color')
  ;
btColor.onclick=_=>
  {
  Root.style.setProperty('--bColor', 'green')
  }
```

```css
:root {
  --bColor  : blue;
  }
.cc{
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80px;
  }
.curve {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid var(--bColor);
  transform: translateX(50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="cc">
  <div class="curve"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="bt-color">change color</button>
```

Comment: need it to be progressive  and not on a single step change. we can achieve in progressive way like loader?

Comment: @Sumanthmadey you should have written this from the start, then I would have used my time differently to answer this other question which is still incomplete anyway